# Using Ruby to get list of installed android packages from android device

Tags: android, ruby

I am using ruby to install/uninstall apps from a device and now ran into the problem of retrieving an array of installed packages from that device. This is my def:

```
def get_installed_packages(device)
  @temp = [] 
  alert "Gets list of installed apps on the follwing device #{device}"
  @temp << `adb -s #{device} shell "pm list packages -f"`

  alert @temp.join(', ')
end
```

This returns a big nothing, I can see the android console running and showing the packages but not populating my @temp. So, this is not the right way.
Is it possible to get the list of the installed apps from a ruby script?
Thanks.

Comment: I don’t use android, but I use backticks. As fair I remember, they return string, so you don't have to use `join` (I think that is your problem here, but you must check it). String doesn’t have `join` method, so it should give you an error: `NoMethodError: undefined method \`join\' for "":String` (or return nothing if something went bad). Well, if above won’t work, try to use this command in the irb/pry session.

Comment: Hello, thx for the point to use irb. Did tried that and : <code>irb(main):021:0> @packages =`adb -s 009f04f6461ba6bb  shell "pm list packages -f"`</code> next if i print @packages it returns the entire list. But using the same lines in my def, i still have nothing.

Comment: Just before `alert @temp.join(', ')`, check the `@temp` (`puts`/`p`). It should contain the same (or at least similar) string like running that command outside the `def`. If `@temp` has indeed that string, the problem is in the next line (method alert: `alert @temp`).
ps. instead of `<code>` you must use `\`your code\``. And to put `\``, you must put backslash before backtick: `\\``.

Comment: i find this thing strange. trying to display the available devices i find the same pattern : `irb(main):006:0> puts devices
List of s attached
4df18ae013be9f45
=> nil` the last bit "=> nil" means it's null even if the list is not null?

Comment: I think code in your last comment is invalid, however `puts "string"` should display the `string` AND returns nil.